# How to validate url in Yii

Tags: yii

I have a field in yii which needs url input only. I use url validation of yii.

```
array('source_link','url')
```

but this is validating both http and https. I want to use only https.I used defaultScheme.

```
array('source_link','url', 'defaultScheme'=>'https')
```

but it is still same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defaultScheme` param is for prepending prefix to url, for example `http`, if there is no prefix like that. From documentation:

> **public string $defaultScheme;**
>
> the default URI scheme. If the input doesn't contain the scheme part,
>   the default scheme will be prepended to it (thus changing the input).
>   Defaults to null, meaning a URL must contain the scheme part.

**You should use `validSchemes`:**

> **public array $validSchemes;**
>
> list of URI schemes which should be considered valid. By default, http
>   and https are considered to be valid schemes.

So you rule should looks like this:

```
array('source_link','url', 'validSchemes'=>array('https'))
```